# Oracle 10g: Search in previous rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table events with columns `sr, event_id, category, date, location, Done_YN`, etc.) where `category` is single character encoded as `D`, `N`, `A`, `E`, or `F` (having meaning of: Day, Night, Afternoon, Evening, Full Day).

MY Question is how should I write my SQL query (For Oracle 10g)  to fetch ID, DATE of recent 'Day' events along with previously 'Night' category event ID and Date done at the same location Id.

Comment: It is always helpful to add some sample data and expected output :]

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a column called `date` and `Done_YN` I'm assuming you've actually used case-sensitive identifiers, so:

```
SELECT "event_id", "date"
FROM   "events"
WHERE  ("date" >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
        AND "date" < TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) /*today*/
        AND "category" = 'D' /*Day*/)
OR     ("date" >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
        AND "date" < TRUNC(SYSDATE) /*yesterday*/
        AND "category" = 'N' /*Night*/);
```

If you add `location` you should then be able to sort these by location to find co-located events.

Comment: The double quotes are most probably wrong. `"event_id"` is not the same column name as `even_id` in Oracle.

Comment: It looks like 'event_id' to me.

Answer (score 0):

Below is query, where I used [row_number()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function to enumerate events partitioned by location and category descending by date.
Next I took only last events (row_number=1).

The outer query joins day and night events according to location. Full join is used in case there is only day or only night event found so we list it with nulls in second section (like for location LA in my example).

I renamed your "date" column to edate, because `date` is reserved word, better to avoid it as column name.

```
with ev as (
  select * from (
      select sr, event_id, category, edate, location,
          row_number() over (partition by location, category order by edate desc) rn
        from events where category in ('D', 'N') )
    where rn=1)
select location, dev.event_id day_event_id, dev.edate day_event_date, 
    nev.event_id ngt_event_id, nev.edate ngt_event_date
  from (select * from ev where category = 'D') dev
    full join (select * from ev where category = 'N') nev using (location)
```

Sample results:

```
LOCATION  DAY_EVENT_ID  DAY_EVENT_DATE  NGT_EVENT_ID  NGT_EVENT_DATE
--------  ------------  --------------  ------------  --------------
NY                   1  2015-01-01                 7  2015-01-07
LA                   6  2015-01-06
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8291/1)